# How to run Google Sheets macro everyday at a specific time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to automatically run a macro on Google Sheets everyday at 5:00 PM?

I've tried setting a time-driven trigger every minute to run a function, for example:

```
if (spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue() == '5:00 PM') {
    // run macro
  }
```

However, it doesn't always trigger successfully. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `However, it doesn't always trigger successfully.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, it seems that your showing script is incomplete. So, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating `However, it doesn't always trigger successfully.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I have a feeling that your understanding of `triggers` and `scripts` may be incomplete. A "trigger" `lets Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event occurs` and there is a particular type of trigger called a **[Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)** that `lets scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval`. If your "time-driven trigger" is configured to execute daily at 5:00pm then you don't need the `IF` statement in your script.

Comment: Getting it exactly at 5:00 PM may be a problem.  But getting some where between 5 and 6 should be no problem.  Also take a look the the trigger event object as it typically has time and date information in it I believe.